# Is it ArrayFormula I want?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What I want is in the [data tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j5HIfryFDo8eL1STF8fDlobK6U59dhtC6Z4w9n4E7E0/edit#gid=64223385), cell B10, to be a count of the number of times a certain person will appear in any of three different columns in the ALT_ELA tab (J, X, and AL, you'll see them in the COUNTIFS formula that I have in there, but that's not giving me what I need, since that's asking for rows in which the name occurs in all three places).

So in column B i want the count of total places that person is assigned, and then in column C I want to track the number of 1s that that person has earned.

So if a name exists in J, X, and/or AL, how many times, and then how many 1s has that person earned in either N, AB and/or AP.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You do not have any data n `AL` column.

Comment: No, not yet, there will be at some point, but that wouldn't effect this anyway, would it? As the sheet is populated over time, the values will be either 0 or 1, and I need to system to count them as they're added.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster oh wow thanks, no one's ever mentioned this, i thought making a dummy table and sharing it in the post *was* the protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the article [What Does the COUNTIFS Function Do in Google Sheets?](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/countif-countifs-google-sheets/), the `countifs()` function will only count if all the criteria have been satisfied. In the sheets provided, the columns J, X, AL didn't have the value "Craig" which was why you were getting 0.

You can try this syntax in cell `B10`, so that you can sum up the specific name in column J,X,AL *(the criterion is based on the name provided in Column A-Contributors)*:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(ALT_ELA!J:J,A10),COUNTIF(ALT_ELA!X:X,A10),COUNTIF(ALT_ELA!AL:AL,A10))
```

[image]

Then on column C, to track the 1s on columns N, AB and/or AP, you can use the `query()` function with `sum()`:

```
=SUM(QUERY(ALT_ELA!A:AP,"Select N,AB,AP where (J = '"&A10&"' or X = '"&A10&"' or AL = '"&A10&"')",0))
```

[image]

*Note: I have tried adding 1s and names on the mentioned columns so the result in the screenshots may not be aligned with yours.*